# count value in a array into ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, each

I have this data : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/API/moulinette/radio/posts.json , from cakephp app, it's song by song, with attached votes

I use it as a service into a angularjs app, and i displayed it like this in html :

```
            <div ng-repeat="song in songs | orderBy:'Radio.idSong' | notesong:'Radiovote'" class="list-group-item" id="{{song.Radio.idSong}}" ng-class="{ 'active' : songPlayed_name == song.Radio.name }" ng-if="songs">
                <span>{{song.Radio.idSong}} - {{song.Radio.title}}</span><br />
                <span>{{note}}%</span>
            </div>
```

So, i want to count each attached vote, and define with values 'good' or 'bad', the % of likes

I try to made this filter :

```
/* notesong */
app.filter('notesong', function() {
    return function(input) {

    // counter init
    var countGood = 0;

    // if there is no votes, so note is zero
    if (!angular.isArray(input)) {
        var note = 0;
    } else {
        // loop for each vote (from Radiovote array, each value)
        angular.forEach(input, function () {
            if (input.value == 'good') {
                countGood = countGood + 1;
            }
        });
        var note = (countGood * input.length) / 100;
    }

    // final return
    return note;

    };
});
```

It's not working apparently (no errors, and no data displayed), so, what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the filter in the wrong place. Instead of using it on the `ng-repeat` you should use it on the property you want to bind, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs | orderBy:'Radio.idSong'" class="list-group-item" id="{{song.Radio.idSong}}" ng-class="{ 'active' : songPlayed_name == song.Radio.name }" ng-if="songs">
  <span>{{song.Radio.idSong}} - {{song.Radio.title}}</span><br />
  <span>{{song.Radiovote | notesong}}%</span>
</div>
```

There's also a problem with the way you are looping the votes in your filter. Update the following lines:

```
// loop for each vote (from Radiovote array, each value)
angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
  if (item.value == 'good') {
    countGood = countGood + 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thks :) but the note is '0' for each song

Comment: There was a problem in your filter as well. I've updated my answer. Please check if it helps.